# PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(Rect, int) constructor throws issue

Tags: android

I am following the informations provided in the URL http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html to generate PDF, but the IDE complains `constructor PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(Rect, int) is undefined` on the below line

```
new PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the package `android.graphics.pdf` was added only at the SDK version 19, seems like docs still have issues. If you'll take a look on the following [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder.html), you'll find, that the only possible constructor for `PageInfo.Builder` is the following:

```
PageInfo.Builder (int pageWidth, int pageHeight, int pageNumber)
```

The same constructor can be also found at the source code. So you should use this one instead of this:

```
PageInfo.Builder (Rect rect, int someNumber)
```

Comment: Did this influence your ability to draw content inside the document? I think internally the pageWidth and pageHeight are probably used to generate the Rect internally these days since it's much clearer, though it would have been nice if they had just left in the old one too due to their tutorials.